# Manually adding Firebase users with custom claims

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing an app that only manually added users can access (I add a user manually in the `auth` tab in the Firebase console with a given Email and Password, and then the user can log in using the mobile app).

I want to add to some users the role of "Manager" while adding then manually. I've heard `Custom Claims` can be a solution for it, but I couldn't find a way to manually add `Custom Claims` in the Firebase console.

Is it possible? And if it's not, how can I add a Firebase user role when creating users manually?

Thank you!

Comment: The docs didn't help? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Comment: @wiesson Thank you, I've read the docs, but there was no explanation about adding a `Custom Claim` manually using the Firebase console

Answer (score 3):

*As explained in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62357125/setting-custom-claims-manually-in-firebase-console/62360553#62360553) (I cannot mark it as duplicate since it is not already accepted):*

---

At the time of writing, there isn't any way to add Custom Claims manually from the Firebase console. You need to use a Cloud Function (or a a server that you fully control, i.e. a “[privileged server environment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk)” as explained in the doc, in which you can use one of the Admin SDKs, Node.js, Java, Python,Go or C#).

---

I usually use a temporary Cloud Function to set claims to a specific user, as follows:

```
exports.assignSpecificClaim = functions.firestore
    .document('tempoSpecificClaim/{tempoId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const claims = {};
        claims['admin'] = true;
        claims['batman'] = true;

        const userId = '26sn9Fvn0hNNG7cs4M1agjzhN3y2';

        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userId, claims);
    });
```

As you can see, this Function is triggered by the creation of a document in a temporary `tempoSpecificClaim` Firestore Collection.

Here is how to use it:

- First, you add a specific security rule to your Firestore Security rules:
  `match /tempoSpecificClaim/{tempoDoc} {allow read, write: if false;}.` This way it is only possible to create a doc in the `tempoSpecificClaim` collection from the Firebase Console.
- You paste the user uid in the Cloud Function, you re-deploy it and create a dummy document in the Collection. The Cloud Function is triggered and the claims are set.
- When done with your tests, you delete the `tempoSpecificClaim` collection together with the corresponding security rule, you delete the temporary Cloud Function in the `index.js` and redeploy it.

It is not a very elaborated and elegant method, but it does the job…